# How do you prevent duplicate form submissions without using a query string?

Tags: php, session

I want to be able to display a message like "Client Updated" on a form submission, but I don't want to hit refresh and it ask me if I want to re-submit the form.

I also don't want to use a query string, because by adding ?msg=success to the URL, now everytime I refresh the page after updating I get the message every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['update-client'])) {

        //do stuff, then:

        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'success';
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        exit;
    };
?>

<h1>Clients</h1>

<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    ?>
        <div class="alert">
            Client Updated
        </div>
    <?
    };

    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
?>

<form>
    <!--  Update Client Form-->
</form>
```